# intercept shutdown in windows using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, shutdown, intercept

I want to write a vbscript that will wait for windows shutdown and intercept to carry out proper action before shutting down. I want this to be in vbscript since am using it for administration.

Comment: In addition, i just found a close example of waht am looking for. Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than that, ever since Windows 2000 you can use the **Group Policy setting** (or Local Policy even if you're not in a domain) to set the **Shutdown Script** which will be called, as the name implies, when someone is trying to shutdown the computer. For more info, check out [MSKB #198642](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198642).

Comment: the truth is , i will be runing this scrip[t most of the time in limited user account, it can be cumbersome to do this manually over 50 systems am managing. the script is just to ensure a proper shutdown of other applications am using to monitor network before windows shutsdown

Comment: In my experience, Windows still continues to shut down, so the script may not be able to finish running.